# List of software projects "open sourced" by private companies

Tags: data-request, software, open-source

I am interested in a dataset listing software projects that started as closed projects within private companies but were at some point relicensed and released to the public.  At a minimum, I'd like to know the name of the project and the date when it was released as OSS.  My starting point is the Wikipedia list [List of formerly proprietary software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_formerly_proprietary_software).